# Inheritance with JavaScript Prototypes in a Modular System

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am building a JavaScript application in which I have a main JS object i'll call `App` for for this post.

The `App` object has a `modules` property that holds a set of Module objects with a module name as the object property name on `App.modules`.

A `module` is a user contributed add-on to my app that will use `Prototypes` to extend a `CoreModule` object.

The `App.modules` object will add new modules to the object like this...

```
App.modules[moduleName] = module-object-instance;
```

So what I am describing has 3 objects in total if there was 1 module registered....

- App
- CoreModule
- userBuiltMOdule

In my `App` code I want to have a `registerModule()` function that does this...

```
// this will create a new instance of "moduleName" and add it to this.modules[moduleName] object
// for example I am hardcoding the module name as theres 1 module now
registerModule: function(moduleName, moduleClass) {

    // create new instance of module
    this.modules[moduleName] = new bookmarksModule();

    // run moduleName.init() function from the main App 
    this.modules[moduleName].init();

    console.log('App.registerModulemoduleName) function ran and created new instance of '+moduleName+'object');
},
```

---

Now to make a user module extend from my `CoreModule` I have a helper function on `CoreModule` named `createModule` that the user module can call that will combine the properties of the user module and the core module into the prototype of the user module...

```
createModule: function(moduleObject){
    var moduleCoreInstance = Object.create(this);
    // add sub-modules properties and functions to CoreModule 
    Object.keys(moduleObject).forEach(function(key){
        moduleCoreInstance[key] = moduleObject[key];
    });
    return moduleCoreInstance;
},
```

---

To create a user module now I do this...

```
var bookmarksModule = ModuleCore.createModule({
    name: 'bookmarks',
    init: function(){
        console.log('bookmarksModule init() function ran from App object '+this.name+')');
    }
});
```

`bookmarksModule` now has `name`, `init()`, `registerSidebar() from the CoreModule`

---

Now to my problem with this system...

In my App.registerMOdule()` function I can not use:

```
// create new instance of module
this.modules[moduleName] = new bookmarksModule();
```

This will give an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: bookmarksModule is not a constructor
    at App.registerModule (yuzulat.js:51)
    at App.init (yuzulat.js:43)
```

If I instead switch the code with this it works:

```
this.modules[moduleName] = bookmarksModule;
```

where `bookmarksModule` is the user module that called `var bookmarksModule = ModuleCore.createModule()`

So my question is, is there a way to extend from `CoreModule` like I do right now but allow my `App.registerModule()` to create a new instance of the user module?

---

Below is my full example code...

JSBin Demo - http://jsbin.com/yuzulat/1/edit?js,console,output

```
var ModuleCore = {

    // add ModuleCore prototype functions to the new sub module as well as pass in the sub-modules properties and functions and return to 
    // the sub-module so the sub-modules prototype will have CoreModules properties and function and its own properties and function merged
    // into its prototype
    createModule: function(moduleObject){
        var moduleCoreInstance = Object.create(this);
        // add sub-modules properties and functions to CoreModule 
        Object.keys(moduleObject).forEach(function(key){
            moduleCoreInstance[key] = moduleObject[key];
        });
        return moduleCoreInstance;
    },


    registerSidebar: function(){
        console.log('registerSidebar(sidebar options for module '+this.name+')');
    }
};

var bookmarksModule = ModuleCore.createModule({
    name: 'bookmarks',
    init: function(){
        console.log('bookmarksModule init() function ran from App object '+this.name+')');
    }
});


(function() {
  function App() {
    this.settings = {};
    this.modules = {};
  };

  App.prototype = {

    // run registerModules
    init: function(bookmarksModule) {

      console.log('App.init() function ran');

      // call App.registerModule() and pass in bookmarksModule module name
      this.registerModule('bookmarksModule', bookmarksModule);
    },

    // this will create a new instance of "moduleName" and add it to this.modules[moduleName] object
    // for example I am hardcoding the module name as theres 1 module now
    registerModule: function(moduleName, moduleClass) {

      // create new instance of module
      this.modules[moduleName] = new bookmarksModule();
      //this.modules[moduleName] = moduleClass;

      // run moduleName.init() function from the main App 
      this.modules[moduleName].init();

      console.log('App.registerModulemoduleName) function ran and created new instance of moduleName object');
    },


    // itterate this.modules object and call this.initModules() function on each module object
    registerModules: function() {
      console.log('App.registerModules() function ran');
    }

  };

  window.App = App;

})();


// create new instance of App
var App = new App();
App.init(bookmarksModule);


// call App.registerModule() and pass in bookmarksModule module name
App.registerModule('bookmarksModule', bookmarksModule);
```

Comment: `this.modules[moduleName] = new bookmarksModule();` ? What about the `moduleClass` parameter ?

Comment: @Poster `createModule` gives a plain object, `new` works with functions.

Comment: @procrastinator `moduleClass` are you asking where it is or saying it creates an instance of the object?  If the 1st `moduleClass` is meant to be the same as `var bookmarksModule = ModuleCore.createModule()` in the example user created module above

Comment: @JasonDavis I mean you have a parameter called `moduleClass` and you never use it. Looks weird.

Comment: @procrastinator updated comment when you posted this.  It was just from creating this post from 2 different demos I was experimenting with

Comment: @JasonDavis Clean up your code then, hard to help otherwise.

Comment: @procrastinator updated and Baint posted something below if you interested in looking too

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the contructor generate modules that inherit coremodule immedialitely, let the user create a simple constructor and create an addModule function for the App.

This function should take in an object, make it inherit coreModule and add it to the module list immedialitely.

```
App = {
    // ...

    addModule: function(name, module) {
        // make module inherit coreModule
        this.modules[name] = module;
    },

    // ...
};

function MyModule() {
    // Stuff
}

App.addModule(new MyModule());
```

Comment: Inside my `App` I plan to call a function named `init()` on the user module.  In there init() function they can basically run there modules functionality and call other functions and properties in there module object and in the `CoreModule` object.  If I was to extend the module from inside the `App` like your demo would they still be able to access `CoreModule` functions in there module code as its added after the fact or would it work out as expected?

Comment: I'll test it.  Over the last few months I have tried a million different `module` patterns to try an build a module system where the `App` and the `module` can both access each other

Comment: Also to extend the `CoreModule` inside the `App.addModule()` would I just  create a new instance of `CoreModule` and then merge the prototypes of the two with something like `this.modules[name] =  $.extend(CoreModule.prototype, module.prototype);`